# Date format Error(Month conflict)

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to convert string of format `yyyy-mm-dd` to `dd-MMM-yy`. I am getting correct year and days but for month it is showing only jan irrespective of my input. How to fix it?

```
String input = "2013-09-14";
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
Date date = null;
try {
    date = format1.parse(input);
    String temp = format2.format(date);
    System.out.println(temp);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
14-Jan-13
```

But I should get:

```
14-Oct-13
```

Comment: yyyy-mm-dd is year-minute-day. You need yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: What makes you expect October? I know that `Date`’s deprecated `setMonth` method would understand 9 as October, but `SimpleDateFormat`, albeit troublesome in many respects, I would still expect it to understand `09` as September.

Comment: Please, for your own sake and ours, search and research before asking. You will get a good answer faster that way. This question has been asked with smaller variations many times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mm` is for **minute**

you need `MM` or `MMM` for **month**.

See [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

*mm* is for minutes. *MM* is for months.

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest latest API `LocalDate` which not requires `try/catch` and which is easier to use :

```
String input = "2013-09-14";

LocalDate inputDate = LocalDate.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
String format = inputDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy"));

System.out.println(format);
```

---

- `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE` is shortcut for `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");`
- `LocalDate inputDate = LocalDate.parse(input);` would also work because `ISO_DATE` the default `format`

[`DateTimeFormatter doc (patterns)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: Brilliant! Using the built-in `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE` saves us from specifying an explicit format pattern, thereby eliminating the risk of getting the case wrong.

Comment: @OleV.V. also because ISO_DATE is the standard format (use if you print without specidy a format) it's useless to specify it for parse

Comment: Citation "not requires try/catch", well, the compiler does not need it but if the input does not match the pattern then parsing can still throw a runtime exception which has to be handled anyway.

Comment: @MenoHochschild yep, like ALL the things in Java, is the input is not good you can have a exception but we don't put try/catch everywhere ;) So using this and not Simple... seems easier to me

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is case sensitive:

MM is month, mm is Minute:

```
 SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

For more Information read The javadoc of [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDat)

Answer (score -3):

personally i used a pattern to do this,

```
LocalTime w = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT.plus(d);
s = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss").format(w);
```

and i advise you to use java 8 date type instead

Comment: Why you suggest TimePattern, when the OP clearly needs a date pattern?

Comment: it's just an example